# How to call vim function from within map and ":split"

Tags: vim

I would like to map a key using "map" from within my vimrc file like this:

```
map <C-I> :split ~/some/file
```

That command actually works fine.

My question is: how do I call a vim function (in this case, "resolve()") on that file path from within the map/split line.  This doesn't work, but hopefully you get the point:

```
map <C-I> :split =resolve("~/some/file")
```

Perhaps it uses call()? I'm obviously confused about vim scripting in general.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two additional ways of doing this which will work outside of a mapping and are safer then using `<C-r>` (POSIX allows filenames with any byte but `\x00`, including control codes):

```
nnoremap <C-i> :execute "split" fnameescape(resolve("~/some/file"))<CR>
nnoremap <C-i> :split `=resolve("~/some/file")`<CR>
```

In second case no escaping is needed, but filename must not contain newline (it won't hurt, just will produce an error).

Another things to consider:

1. Use `nnoremap`, it will enable you to, for example, exchange meanings of `;` and `:` without changing maps and also prevent your map from being spoiled by plugins unless they redefine `<Tab>` mapping (`<C-i>` is same as `<Tab>`). Forced normal mode is here because in other modes it will produce unexpected results.
2. Escape arguments: `fnameescape(resolve("~/some/file"))`, it will prevent errors for filenames with spaces.
3. You can write `<C-r>` where @Austin Taylor suggested to write raw control code. I don't like having any of them inside a file because it will make diffs not viewable in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```
map <C-I> :split ^R=resolve("~/some/file")<cr><cr>
```

If you are putting this in `.vimrc`, you type `C-v C-r` to type the `^R` character.

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten that ^R is "insert" for command mode.